# Is that Matt Smith's real voice in Patient Zero?

Tags: voice-acting, patient-zero

[Matt Smith](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1741002/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) is an English actor known for his role as the Eleventh Doctor in the TV show Doctor Who, and he appears in the film [Patient Zero](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3458254/) with an American accent.

His voice is very different in this film, and I'm having a hard time believing this is really his voice. It's not the American accent that is different, but the pitch and tone sound like a completely different person.

Did they voice over his lines or is this his real voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the indications are this this is Smith doing a *somewhat interesting* American accent. It's not surprising that it's coming off different from his usual English one. It's *forced* and so it naturally sounds different.

For an example of **multiple** US accents from Matt Smith see this Youtube clip